# TFSConfig Accounts /ResetOwner ... fails

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to move a TFS Server (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252516.aspx)), but everything is not working well. When I get to the Change Ownership step, the following command fails:

```
TFSConfig Accounts /ResetOwner /SQLInstance:<ServerName> /DatabaseName:<DatabaseName>
```

The error on the Tfs_Configuration table:

```
TF30065: An unhandled exception occurred.
```

The error on the Tfs_DefaultConfiguration table:

```
TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.
```

I skipped the marked transactions, because I [could not get it working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150825/sql-marked-transaction-log-confusion).

Comment: vote to migrate to serverfault

Answer (score 1):

You must remap your TFS database before config your accounts.

Please see following links

[RemapDB Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee349262.aspx)

[Account Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253107.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I no longer have a need for this, so I won't be able to test it.